# How to create new arrays from existing multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multi-dimensional array (this is only an extract) and would like to dynamically create a set of one-dimensional arrays and add values.

What I have:

```
0 => 
     0 => Image
     1 => DE
     2 => Hamburg-S02-I01
     3 => 54
     4 => Button
1 => 
     0 => Image
     1 => GB
     2 => London-S01-I01
     3 => 51
     4 => Button
2 => 
     0 => Image
     1 => GB
     2 => London-S01-I04
     3 => 60
     4 => Button
3 => 
     0 => Image
     1 => DE
     2 => Berlin-S02-I01
     3 => 57
     4 => Button
4 => 
     0 => Image
     1 => DE
     2 => Hamburg-S02-I01
     3 => 52
     4 => Button
```

What I need:

```
$Hamburg = array('Hamburg-S02-I01', 'Hamburg-S02-I01');
$London= array('London-S01-I01', 'London-S01-I04');
$Berlin= array('Berlin-S02-I01');
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't want individual variables! Believe me. You probably *really* want `$cities = ['Hamburg' => ['Hamburg...', ...], 'London' => ...]`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea - I like it! Any idea how I would achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $new_array[explode('-',$val[2])[0]][] = $val;
}
```

That code travels through your array - that I arbitrarily named `$array` - and push every sub_array in it inside sub_arrays in another array which key will be whatever is before the first hyphen character in the third entry of the original sub_array. I don't know if it's what you were after, but maybe at least it will inspire you.

Content of new array :

    `(3)
    [Hamburg] => (2)
      [0] => (5)
        [0] => Image
        [1] => DE
        [2] => Hamburg-S02-I01
        [3] => 54
        [4] => Button
      [1] => (5)
        [0] => Image
        [1] => DE
        [2] => Hamburg-S02-I01
        [3] => 52
        [4] => Button
    [London] => (2)
      [0] => (5)
        [0] => Image
        [1] => GB
        [2] => London-S01-I01
        [3] => 51
        [4] => Button
      [1] => (5)
        [0] => Image
        [1] => GB
        [2] => London-S01-I04
        [3] => 60
        [4] => Button
    [Berlin] => (1)
      [0] => (5)
        [0] => Image
        [1] => DE
        [2] => Berlin-S02-I01
        [3] => 57
        [4] => Button`

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $new_array[explode('-',$val[2])[0]][] = $val[2];
}
```

The second version pushes only the third entry, since it seems that's what you're after.

Output :

    `(3)
    [Hamburg] => (2)
      [0] => Hamburg-S02-I01
      [1] => Hamburg-S02-I01
    [London] => (2)
      [0] => London-S01-I01
      [1] => London-S01-I04
    [Berlin] => (1)
      [0] => Berlin-S02-I01`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
$cities = array();
foreach($images as $image) {
    $parts = explode('-',$image[2]);
    $city = $parts[0];
    if(!isset($cities[$city])) $cities[$city] = array();
    $cities[$city][] = $image[2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...  `$myarray` is an array containing your example, above.

```
$cities = array();
foreach($myarray as $key => $val){
    unset($tmp);
    $tmp = explode("-",$val[2]);
    if(!is_array($cities[$tmp[0]])){
        $cities[$tmp[0]] = array();
    }
    array_push($cities[$tmp[0]], $val[2]);       
}
```

I am...

- Looping through your original array.
- Using the variable `$tmp` to split appart the element with the city name.
- Using just the city name, I'm testing if I have a new array element with that name.
- If not, create that array inside `$cities`.
- Either way, push the city string into the city array.

Comment: Thanks! It works but shows this error message multiple times

Notice: Undefined index: Hamburg in index.php on line:    if(!is_array($cities[$tmp[0]])){

Comment: :-)  That's something @Adder added that I forgot about.  Change that line to read: `if(!isset($cities[$tmp[0]]) || !is_array($cities[$tmp[0]])){`